# Java method references while exception handling

Tags: java, java-8

I have one method which throws checked exception:

`private void testCacheExpiration() throws InterruptedException`

I am trying to create a generic wrapper that will handle the exception gracefully.

```
private Runnable handleNonTestException(Runnable r) {
    return () -> {
        try {
            r.run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(NON_TEST_EXCEPTION_MSG, e);
            errors.add(new Error(e.getMessage(), NON_TEST_EXCEPTION_MSG));
        }
    };
}
```

Now I am using `handleNonTestException(this::testCacheExpiration)` which gives me compile time error `unhandled exception type: InterruptedException` . What may I be missing?

Comment: Maybe, you want to use a [`Callable<Void>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)?

Comment: You're providing `this::testCacheExpiration` as an implementation of the functional interface `Runnable`'s `run` method, which is not declared to throw an `InterruptedException`.

Comment: The body of `handleNonTestException` does not make any difference here.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yep, realized that after a while. Tx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `testCacheExpiration` method signature doesn't conform to the `run` method's signature in runnable interface (which doesn't throw any exception)

Following changes solved it:

```
@FunctionalInterface
private interface ThrowingRunnable <E extends Exception> {
    void run() throws Exception;
}

private Runnable handleNonTestException(ThrowingRunnable<? extends Exception> r) {
    return () -> {
        try {
            r.run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(NON_TEST_EXCEPTION_MSG, e);
            errors.add(new Error(e.getMessage(), NON_TEST_EXCEPTION_MSG));
        }
    };
}`
```

Comment: What’s the point of this type parameter you are not using?